# allowing partial many-to-many access to models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I've got a Rails app where users can create notebooks and share them with other users. Users can edit everything about their own notebooks, but only parts of notebooks shared with them. Right now my models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :notebooks

    # other user things...
end

class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    # other notebook things...
end
```

And in my controllers, I allow users to edit their own notebooks. Now I need to figure out how to allow other users access to parts of notebooks shared with them. I want to do something like:

```
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user # the admin user for this notebook
    has_many :users # all users with access
end
```

I'm not sure how to set this up, as I'm new to Rails. Any advice on how to structure this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out `has_many_and_belongs_to`? Or `has_many, :through`? Check out the Rails guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

```
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :user_notebooks
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notebooks, through: :user_notebooks
end
```

Also, watch your plurals (i.e., it should be `has_many :users`, not `has_many :user`).

Comment: It seems like `has_and_belongs_to_many` would let me create the many-to-many relationship, but how do I enforced the ownership of notebooks that way? Wouldn't I just get `notebook.users`, without making the distinction between owner and someone who's allowed access?

Comment: What about an `:owner` or `:creator` field in `Notebook`, and store the user ID of the creator there?